# Error in if else statement in linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell

Being newbie in linux shell scripting, I had tried to implement the following code in `test.sh` :

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is some secure program that uses security.
clear 
VALID_PASSWORD="secret" #this is our password.

echo "Please enter the password:"
read PASSWORD

if [ "$PASSWORD" == "$VALID_PASSWORD" ]; then
    echo "You have access!";
else
    echo "ACCESS DENIED!";
fi
```

But while executing the script, it shows me following error:

```
Please enter the password:
1234
./tst1.sh: 9: [: 1234: unexpected operator
ACCESS DENIED!
```

I am unable to debug this error. Appreciate the much needed help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Shell, you need to use the POSIX comparison `=`.

That is, use:

```
if [ "$PASSWORD" = "$VALID_PASSWORD" ]; then
#                ^
```

Instead of

```
if [ "$PASSWORD" == "$VALID_PASSWORD" ]; then
#                ^^
```

You can have a good read to [What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) in order to see all the variances. Basically, if you are in Shell, use the POSIX tiny set of possibilities; if you are in Bash, you can use other things such as `[[`:

```
            |   new test [[   |   old test [
----------------------------------------------
            |      >          |      \>
string      |      <          |      \<
comparison  |   = (or ==)     |      =
            |      !=         |      !=
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I would like to ask you if you could explain it to why it is not working in `shell` while working on the `terminal`?

Comment: @abhi1610 because most probably you are working under Bash, where the `if [ "$var1" == "$var" ]` comparison is possible. Check your shell writing `echo $0` in your console.

Comment: Yes. It is returning me `bash`.

Comment: OK, then this explains the different behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The comparison operator `==` you use to compare the two strings is a [Bash](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) extension, it doesn't exist in basic `sh`, which instead uses the [`test`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) command which uses *single* `=` to compare strings.

Comment: Good one! I was looking for references and couldn't find this good one.

Answer (score 1):

Correct Syntax for If - Else in Linux is below

```
if [ "$1" = "cool" ]
then
    echo "Cool Beans"
else
    echo "Not Cool Beans"
fi
```